# Django South vs Migratory

Tags: django

Looking for a comparison between Django South and Migratory for migrations in production for a not-so-heavy-backend app. Which one would be preferable?

Answer (score 9):

South has, for good reasons, become *the* Django migration solution. It works great, is well maintained and has good documentation. Also, if you're using third party reusable apps, they generally use South for migrations. So by using South, you'll be able to migrate your own apps as well as third party apps with the same tool.

Migratory, on the other hand, was [last updated two years ago](https://bitbucket.org/DeadWisdom/migratory/src), if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

South is a safe choice.
Referring to [Jacob Kaplan Moss's blog post](http://jacobian.org/writing/favorite-apps/) and the result of its unformal poll conducted on twitter "**What's your favorite django app**", South is the #1 django third-party app.

More arguments ?

- South is widely used now among Django developers
- You can find a lots of [South tutorials](http://google.com/search?q=django+south+tutorial) in Google
- South begins to get support in [all kind of pluggable apps](http://google.com/search?q=django+field+%22south+support%22) (django-extensions UUIDField supports it for example, spatial fields in geo-Django, etc...).
- Whenever Django integrates such a migration utility (Hey, Ruby on Rails has one built-in!), you guess which app could be the first candidate...